# How can hide # tag in URL in angular - routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

To make routing works fine in server host, we can enable useHash = true as follow in app-routing.module.ts file.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Actually, with that solution we can navigate within components fine in our application. But it always shows # tag in URL tab.

i.e:
http://00.00.190.147:4202/**#**/request

It seems to be some kind of odd view. Is there any way to hide that or any other way to make perfect routing in host in Angular application.

Comment: To make routing works fine in server host without hash you should properly configure your server https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `ng serve` to serve your app locally it has its own server configuration. You must configure your server likewise so that all routes point to the `index.html`. The angular router observes the browser URL and changes the view of the application. An angular application is a single-page app.

Check out https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml for setting your browser configuration to point to the index.html.

Also, if you have your own APIs using the same domain, you may need to put those paths in the assets array from angular.json so that the angular app doesn't treat them as an angular route and treats them as resources (Just a simple hack!) This is not necessarily required if you are using a NodeJs server but for IIS it can be a good hack.

E.g.: if your angular app runs at `http://www.example.com` and your APIs are like `http://www.example.com/api/users`, `http://www.example.com/api/user/52`, `http://www.example.com/api/books`, etc, you shall add 'api' in your assets array in angular.json file as anything after `http://www.example.com/api/` will be treated as an asset and not a part of the angular application route.

Doing this, you may set the flag useHash = false or remove it. `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`

Answer (score 0):

Set the useHash to false.

Eg :- RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: false})